# Using JENA API - Getting all the classes from OWL file

Tags: java, jena

Is it possible to get name of all the classes present in OWL file using JENA and store in the Array List?

```
   OntModel base = ModelFactory.createOntologyModel(OntModelSpec.OWL_MEM, null);
    OntModel model = ModelFactory.createOntologyModel(OntModelSpec.OWL_MEM_MICRO_RULE_INF, null);

    String NS = "http://www.abc.com/abcportal/abc.owl" + "#";

base.read("file:abcInstance.owl");
    ExtendedIterator<OntClass> iter = base.listClasses();

    while ( iter.hasNext()){
        System.out.println(iter.next());
    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes it is, see the Javadoc for [OntModel.listClasses](http://jena.sourceforge.net/javadoc/com/hp/hpl/jena/ontology/OntModel.html#listClasses%28%29). You can easily copy the contents of the `Iterator` into an array or `List`. That you're asking the question suggests that you'll probably benefit from reading the [Jena ontology API documentation](https://jena.apache.org/documentation/ontology/)

Comment: If this answers your question, please follow standard practice for StackOverlow and accept the answer. If it doesn't answer the question, please let us know why not.

Comment: Rite now I am able to retrieve the classnames from owl file i.e Schema file. But I cant able to retrieve the classes from instance file i.e owl file which consist of instances/individual. Please see the edit for the code that i used.

Comment: I am doing things related with this. I try to used above code. I need to take only list of class names. From this above code I got output as "http://localhost/new/Food Information " . So, If I need to take only class name "Food Information", What are the changes I need to do?